# jQuery: for each radio button, assign a thumbnail SRC, then use it

Tags: jquery, radio-button, thumbnails

I have a main image and some thumbnails, then some radio buttons.

I want to click the radio buttons, assign to it one of the thumbnail's SRCs in order, and change the main image SRC.

That's what I tried so far, but it only changes once (and it changes the main image for the last thumbnail's SRC, no matter what radio button do I click).

I'm a pretty clumsy coder (a survivor though), so sorry for this mess, just trying to get around it!

```js
 jQuery(".thumbnails-group img").each(function() {  //I go through the thumbnails
 
  var imgsrc = this.src; //I get the SRC of each
  
  jQuery(".radio-buttons input:radio").each(function() {  //for each radio button

   jQuery(this).click(function () { //on click
    jQuery('#main-image').attr('src', imgsrc); //change main image SRC using variable
   });

  });
  
 });
```

```css
.thumbnails-group{
  clear: both;
}
.thumbnails-group ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.thumbnails-group img{
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.radio-buttons{
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="main-image" src="http://www.daz3d.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/689303033aebc8cae535000c73c8db4b/h/e/heart-of-the-forest-1.jpg">

<div class="thumbnails-group">
 <ul>
  <li><img src="http://rs177.pbsrc.com/albums/w208/layla818/Forest.jpg~c200"></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.iiasa.ac.at/GenticsImageStore/200/auto/prop//web/home/research/researchPrograms/EcosystemsServicesandManagement/dreamstime_l_14610380_2.png"></li>
  <li><img src="http://rs1382.pbsrc.com/albums/ah245/PhotobucketMKTG/LOHP/Forests.jpg~c200"></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="radio-buttons">
 <p>Click those (not the thumbs, but the radio buttons):</p>
 <input type='radio' id='radio_1' name='type' value='1' />
 <input type='radio' id='radio_2' name='type' value='2' />
 <input type='radio' id='radio_3' name='type' value='3' /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Try stepping through your code in plain language: loop through all images / get src / loop through all radio / assign the src of the current image loop to each radio.  The last image-loop overwrites all the previous image loops.

Comment: How do you know which `img` is meant to be assigned to which `radio` ?

Comment: Can you rearrange the html so they are next to each other?  (ie `<li><img..><input type='radio'></li>`) ?

Comment: Will you always have the same number of `li` as `input type='radio'` ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lega911/cstougfv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index of `checked` radio button, then the `index` can be used to fetch the `img` element at respective index.

```js
var radios = jQuery(".radio-buttons input:radio");
radios.change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var index = radios.index(this);

    imgsrc = jQuery(".thumbnails-group img").eq(index).attr('src');
    //change main image SRC using variable
    jQuery('#main-image').attr('src', imgsrc);
  }
});
```

```css
.thumbnails-group {
  clear: both;
}
.thumbnails-group ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.thumbnails-group img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
.radio-buttons {
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="main-image" src="http://www.daz3d.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/689303033aebc8cae535000c73c8db4b/h/e/heart-of-the-forest-1.jpg">

<div class="thumbnails-group">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://rs177.pbsrc.com/albums/w208/layla818/Forest.jpg~c200">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.iiasa.ac.at/GenticsImageStore/200/auto/prop//web/home/research/researchPrograms/EcosystemsServicesandManagement/dreamstime_l_14610380_2.png">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://rs1382.pbsrc.com/albums/ah245/PhotobucketMKTG/LOHP/Forests.jpg~c200">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="radio-buttons">
  <p>Click those (not the thumbs, but the radio buttons):</p>
  <input type='radio' id='radio_1' name='type' value='1' />
  <input type='radio' id='radio_2' name='type' value='2' />
  <input type='radio' id='radio_3' name='type' value='3' />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the "index" concept.

Answer (score 1):

Why loop through the images, when you could access them specifically with a unique ID?

In the example below I use the `value` of the radio button to build an ID to access the images - and all images have been assigned an ID.

```js
jQuery(".radio-buttons input:radio").each(function() { //for each radio button

  jQuery(this).click(function() { //on click
    var id = $(this).attr("value");
    var imgsrc = $("#img_" + id).attr("src");
    jQuery('#main-image').attr('src', imgsrc); //change main image SRC using variable
  });

});
```

```css
.thumbnails-group {
  clear: both;
}
.thumbnails-group ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.thumbnails-group img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
.radio-buttons {
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="main-image" src="http://www.daz3d.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/689303033aebc8cae535000c73c8db4b/h/e/heart-of-the-forest-1.jpg">

<div class="thumbnails-group">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img id="img_1" src="http://rs177.pbsrc.com/albums/w208/layla818/Forest.jpg~c200">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img id="img_2" src="http://www.iiasa.ac.at/GenticsImageStore/200/auto/prop//web/home/research/researchPrograms/EcosystemsServicesandManagement/dreamstime_l_14610380_2.png">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img id="img_3" src="http://rs1382.pbsrc.com/albums/ah245/PhotobucketMKTG/LOHP/Forests.jpg~c200">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="radio-buttons">
  <p>Click those (not the thumbs, but the radio buttons):</p>
  <input type='radio' id='radio_1' name='type' value='1' />
  <input type='radio' id='radio_2' name='type' value='2' />
  <input type='radio' id='radio_3' name='type' value='3' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
jQuery('.radio-buttons').change(function () { //on change instead
    var idx = jQuery(this).index()
    var imgsrc = jQuery('.thumbnails-group img').eq(idx).attr('src');
    jQuery('#main-image').attr('src', imgsrc);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".radio-buttons input:radio").click(function() {
    var currentVal = $(this).val();
    currentVal = parseInt(currentVal) - 1;
    var targetLI = $(".thumbnails-group ul li").eq(currentVal);
    var src = targetLI.find("img").attr("src");

    jQuery('#main-image').attr('src', src);


  });

});
```

```css
.thumbnails-group {
  clear: both;
}
.thumbnails-group ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.thumbnails-group img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
.radio-buttons {
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="main-image" src="http://www.daz3d.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/689303033aebc8cae535000c73c8db4b/h/e/heart-of-the-forest-1.jpg">

<div class="thumbnails-group">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://rs177.pbsrc.com/albums/w208/layla818/Forest.jpg~c200">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.iiasa.ac.at/GenticsImageStore/200/auto/prop//web/home/research/researchPrograms/EcosystemsServicesandManagement/dreamstime_l_14610380_2.png">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://rs1382.pbsrc.com/albums/ah245/PhotobucketMKTG/LOHP/Forests.jpg~c200">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="radio-buttons">
  <p>Click those (not the thumbs, but the radio buttons):</p>
  <input type='radio' id='radio_1' name='type' value='1' />
  <input type='radio' id='radio_2' name='type' value='2' />
  <input type='radio' id='radio_3' name='type' value='3' />
</div>
```